# Sharing authentication across local resources

Tags: ruby, authentication, architecture, oauth

My web application has a main site, which uses Oauth to log in via a 3rd party service (in this case, it's Github). To preserve the logged in state, the Access Token is stored in a session. So far so good.

There is a part of the application that does background processing. Citing [the 12-factor App](http://12factor.net/), it sounds like I should split this part into it's own resource (essentially, a separate application), and send requests over for (asynchronous) processing via HTTP (See [Backing Resources](http://12factor.net/backing-services)).

The problem is, that part needs access to the 3rd party service as well. How can I securely give it the access token?

If it's helpful, I'm using Sinatra, and a handful of Ruby Gems (Rest-Client, Octokit, etc).

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of research, I determined that the best thing to do is just send the Token over in the message body of the Rest request.

I thought this would be insecure, but it's no more insecure than the request from Github that  gives you your access token in the first place. Of course, it important to use TLS (https) to prevent the token from being intercepted.

Here's a great list of security recommendations to follow with Oauth2 Bearer tokens:

http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#anchor6